# Multiple conditions for a Do..While Loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements, do-while

right basically I am implementing a do while loop. A user is asked to enter a value, and a value is returned back - this is using nested If statements within the do loop. At the end of the loop I am asking whether they want to enter another value, yes or no basically. Here is my code below, I essentially need a way of when the question is asked at the end to perform like...

"Would you like to enter another value?" - "no" - terminates
"Would you like to enter another value?" - "yes" - loop around
"Would you like to enter another value?" - any other value e.g. "maybe" - ask the question again.

The code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class More_Grades {


public static void main (String [] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String A = "Your grade is: ";

    int grade = 0;
    String y;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Grade: ");
        grade = scan.nextInt();
        if (grade < 40) {
            System.out.println(A+"Fail");
        }
        else if (grade >= 40 && grade <= 49) {
            System.out.println(A+"3rd");
        }
        else if (grade >= 50 && grade <= 59) {
            System.out.println(A="2/2");
        }
        else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 69) {
            System.out.println(A+"2/1");
        }
        else if (grade >= 70 && grade < 100) {
            System.out.println(A+"1st");
        }
        else if(grade >100) {
            System.out.println("Invalid grade,Enter a value below 100.");
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to Enter Another? Y/N");
        y = scan.next();

    }while (y.equals("yes"));
    scan.close();
    System.out.println("Thank-You.");
}
```

}

Comment: I hope this isn't homework. Otherwise, in what bizarro universe is it a good idea to post your homework on SO with something like `@author <YourName> - <Your student ID>` contained in it? :-)

Comment: It's late, edited... Thanks though!

Comment: @paxdiablo Maybe he **is** the teacher and want's to write a program that processes the grades of his students. :P

Comment: Just one minor thing. You don't need the first bit of most of those `if` statements since, for example, `grade >= 40` is implied by the fact that it didn't match the previous one `grade < 40`. And you should probably allow people to get 100% without complaining it's invalid (use `<= 100` rather than `< 100`).

Answer (score 1):

You just need another do-while inside your current loop to repeat the question:

```
do {
    ...
   do {
       System.out.println("Would you like to enter another? (yes/no)");
       answer = scan.next();
   } while (!Arrays.asList("yes", "no").contains(answer));
} while (answer.equals("yes");
```